# Setting Up Proper Routing for SQL Instance in Different GCP VPCs without Public Exposure or Gateway VM

Tags: routing, google-cloud-platform, terraform

I'm facing a networking challenge with Google Cloud VPCs and peering, and I'm hoping to get some guidance on how to resolve it. Here's my setup:

I have two VPCs in Google Cloud:

VPC "bastion"
VPC "production"
In my "production" VPC, I've created an SQL instance with Private Service Access (PSA).

In the "bastion" VPC, I have a bastion VM.

I've established peering between the "bastion" and "production" VPCs successfully.

However, I'm stuck at the point where I need to set up routing from my management VM in the "bastion" VPC to access the production database in the "production" VPC through PSA. Unfortunately, it seems I can't add a route to the PSA in the "bastion" VPC's route table because peering can't be used as a next hop.

I'd like to find a solution that allows proper routing without exposing the database to the public internet or adding a gateway VM. Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions on how to achieve this in Google Cloud? Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!